# Arduino PinChangeInt.h yields compiler errors

Tags: c++, arduino-ide

I try to recompile an old arduino sketch that uses PinChangeInt. The compiler reports the following errors:

```
Arduino: 1.6.9 (Windows 7), TD: 1.29, Board: "Arduino/Genuino Micro"

In file included from D:\home\arnold\development\arduino\drone\serial_comm\Rx\Rx.ino:50:0:

C:\packages\arduino\libraries\PinChangeInt/PinChangeInt.h:328:32: error: 'PCMSK1' was not declared in this scope
 PCintPort portC=PCintPort(3, 1,PCMSK1); // port PC==3  (also in pins_arduino.c, Arduino version 022)

C:\packages\arduino\libraries\PinChangeInt/PinChangeInt.h:331:32: error: 'PCMSK2' was not declared in this scope
 PCintPort portD=PCintPort(4, 2,PCMSK2); // port PD==4

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Micro.
```

Does anyone know what is wrong hereand how I might repair these errors? Using Arduino version 1.6.9, version of PinChangeInt is 2402.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Arduino Micro`, `ATMega32U4` is used and it supports only `PCMSK0` on `PORTB`. Other ports doesn't have this capability. See: [ATMega32U4 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf).

You can use also [`attachInterrupt`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt) to process external interrupts. So you have eigth `PCINT0` sources (with one ISR handler for all of them) and five external interrupt sources (each with its own ISR handler) on pins `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` and `7` (HW pins: `PD0` - `PD3`, `PE6`).

Comment: Thanks! I'm investigating it right now. If it works I'll flag this answer as correct.

Comment: I am aware of the attachInterrupt but I was turned to PinChangeInt by http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/ReadReceiver, because attachInterrupt only reads High or Low signals while decoding PWM signals apparently needs the changing signal. This worked ok until I had to translate the code again and I had upgraded from 1.0.5 to 1.6.9. I implemented your suggestion but as other errors popped up I have to be sure that all code compiles before I am sure it all works :-)

Comment: It works, thank you! The PinChangeInt library provides already commented out statements to exclude ports. I excluded all ports except portB and that did it.